# Sort List where object IsNot Nothing

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, list, lambda

I am trying to sort a list of classes, and I need the classes with a subclass that isnot nothing first in the list. I thought the following would work but it doesnt.

```
ListOfClasses.Sort(Function(x, y) If(x.SubClass IsNot Nothing, 1, 0))
```

I know this is a hack at best (not that it works) but I thought it would move the classes up the order where the subclass was not equal to nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that your comparer delegate doesn't follow the proper comparison rules as listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx).  In particular it needs to ensure that if you say 'x is greater than y' that you also say 'y is less than x'.  Here you're only ever saying 'x is greater than y' but you never actually say the opposite.

Here is a comparer function that will properly sort these elements

```
Function Compare(ByVal x as TheType, ByVal y as TheType) As Integer
  If x.SubClass Is Nothing AndAlso y.SubClass Is Nothing Then
    Return 0
  Else If x.SubClass IsNot Nothing AndAlso y.SubClass IsNot Nothing Then
    Return 0
  Else If x.SubClass IsNot Nothing Tehn
    Return -1
  Else
    Return 1
  End If 
End Function
```

This could also be expressed as a statement lambda but as they're only supported in Visual Studio 2010 I chose to write a full function.

Comment: Ahh ok thanks for that, that has cleared up a lot for me. Was hoping to use a lambda expression, but as I am using 2008 it wont be possible. Will look into statement lambda's for the future, they sound interesting...

Answer (score 3):

Your comparer function needs to return -1, 0 or 1 if `x` is less than, equal to or greater than `y`. In your case (since you want to have `Nothing` values at the back):

```
Dim xNull = x Is Nothing
Dim yNull = y Is Nothing

If xNull = yNull Then Return 0 ' either both are Nothing, or neither is.
If xNull Then Return 1
Return -1
```

But be advised that using `Sort` here is unnecessarily inefficient. The operation you need is called [partition](http://cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/partition/) and runs in O(n).

Comment: Thanks, I see what your saying about the comparer function. Not sure about how to use the partition function, will take a closer look at that later.

Comment: @baileyswalk The partition function takes a boolean predicate which just returns whether the current object is `null`. The algorithm of the partition is then just a linear pass over the array from both ends, swapping elements according to that predicate. Since it’s also used in quicksort, the Wikipedia article has a section with a pseudo-code: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Complex_version (but this isn’t using an arbitrary predicate, instead it’s comparing to a pivot).

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is all of the 'Nothing' values at the end (and performance isn't a huge concern in this situation) you can use the default .Sort() on a generic list.  This will give you the 'Nothing' values at the front.  Then you call .Reverse on the list.

```
Dim ListOfClasses As New List(Of Object)
ListOfClasses.Add(Nothing)
ListOfClasses.Add("Something 1")
ListOfClasses.Add(Nothing)
ListOfClasses.Add("Something 2")
ListOfClasses.Add(Nothing)
ListOfClasses.Add("Something 3")

ListOfClasses.Sort()
ListOfClasses.Reverse()
```

Comment: Performance is not a huge concern, I would use this but the sort needs to occurr on the sub class. The lists class type always has a value.